# Extend Class in TypeScript with static member

Tags: typescript, oop

I'm working with NSwag to generate automatic TS file from my backend API. 
The code generated works well, but in soma case I need to extend my class with utility (Es. add rename arry of objects, check constrain,..)

In C# is quite simple:

```cs
    public class Demo {
       public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    public static class DemoExtension{
        public static string GetUpper(this string name){
            /// code removed
        }
    }
```

How can implement this pattern on TS?

I try to follow some thread to talk about interface without success.

```js
/// file test.module.ts
namespace test {
    export class Demo{
        public name : string;
    }
}

/// file demoextension.d.ts
interface DemoExtension {
    getUpper:string(attr:Demo){
        return ...
    }
}

/// file controller.ts
import * as test from './test';

class CtrlDemo
{
    public a : test.Demo;
    constructor(){
        a = new test.Demo();

        // Now TS say me that method not exist
        a.getUpper();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would encourage you to not do it, since when using static method, it means your class won't be testable, instead create a service with same functionality, and inject the service to your classes

Comment: @Reza thaks for your quickest response, but how can I do that? My class is autocreate from NSwag. At the moment the only way is create an extend class from baseClass and add my functionality but in a complex object is quite tedious.

Comment: it depends, what framework is going to use these typescript classes? Angular? (Also take a look at TypeWritter as well) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=frhagn.Typewriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generated code is equal to what you have in C#

```
namespace test {
    export class Demo{
        public name : string;
    }


   /// file demoextension.d.ts
   export class DemoExtension {
      static getUpper(name: string):string {
          return ...
      }
   } 
}

/// file controller.ts
import {Demo, DemoExtension } from './test';


public class CtrlDemo
{
    public CtrlDemo()
    {

        // Now TS say me that method not exist
        DemoExtension.getUpper('hello');
    }
}
```

Comment: i think that method getUpper must be declared STATIC -> static  getUpper(name: string):string

Comment: @andmattia yes yes, I missed it